# Method paginate does not exist in laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

hi I want to paginate rows by relation by writing some codes like this

```
$jobs=auth()->user()->employer->jobs::paginate(10);
```

I tried this code but I got this error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
>   exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write relation without parentheses "()" it will return collection ,  while with "()" will return models that paginate methods available on it.

So your code should :

```
$jobs=auth()->user()->employer->jobs()::paginate(10);
```

Comment: mer30 dadash :)

Answer (score 3):

The last part should probably be `->jobs()->paginate(10);`.

Comment: @MahdiClash Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$jobs=auth()->user()->employer->jobs->paginate(10);
```